# Flask Restful Reqparse required=True Error handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I am using flask_restful.reqparse for parsing arguments. Now I want "name" argument must be required. So I wrote this:

```
from flask_restful import reqparse
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
name= parser.add_argument("name", required=True, help="name is missing")
```

Now I want to handle error that name is not there in request. How can I do this?

Currently, I am sending this request using cURL

```
curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:5000/user \
    -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
    -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
```

It shows 400 Bad Request, I want to send a json response instead of this. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to use [error handlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers)?